# How to fetch value from api response using rest Assured

Tags: java, json, rest, rest-assured, jsonparser

I am new to rest assured. I have a response json as below. where I have multiple nested json in an array having details of spends on particular Merchant. I need to get the spend value of Netflix only. How can I check for the condition where it is Netflix get the absolute value for that only ?

```
{
"data": {
    "content": [
        {
            JsonPath(response);
js.get(key).toString();
```

I used to get value directly using JsonPath but now it is a condition based value I need to fetch.

Here I need to fetch the value of key "absolute" where the merchantBrandName is Netflix, which is again inside a nested json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 options for you.

1. Using `com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath`

```java
List<Double> read = com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(res, "$.data.content[?(@.element.merchantBrandName == 'Netflix')].absolute");
System.out.println(read.get(0));

//2170.220006465912
```

2. Using `io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath`

```java
double abs = JsonPath.from(res).getDouble("data.content.find {it.element.merchantBrandName == 'Netflix'}.absolute");
System.out.println(abs);
//2170.22 
//I don't have time to figure out why it's getting rounded
```

Comment: Thanks @lucas-nguyen-17 . it did worked out. is there a document where I can learn this kinda of complex json parse.

Comment: For the first one, you can check https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath, for the second one https://www.james-willett.com/rest-assured-gpath-json/